# Rails - Saving a new data from other module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have `Client` model and `Contact` model. On the Client page, I put "Add to Contact" button to save it on the `contact` model.

I have this code on my client page:

```
= form_for(@contact, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-horizontal ajax-form add-to-contact', style: 'margin-bottom: 0;', 'data-model-name' => 'contact'}) do |f|
  = f.text_field :type, :value => 'clients'
  = f.text_field :client_id, :value => client.id
  = f.submit "Add to Contact", class: 'btn btn-success btn-submit-add-to-contact'
```

clients_controler.rb

```
def index
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:client_id], params[:type])
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.js {}
      else
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

And I have coffeesript code that when I submit it, it will save to `contact` model:

```
  $(document).on "click", ".btn-submit-add-to-contact", ->
    $(this).prop "disabled", true
    $(this).val "Added to Contacts!"
    $(".add-to-contact").submit()
```

But there's a problem on saving. All of my clients save, as in they're looping and automatically saving although I'm not submitting other client. Please help.

Comment: We'll need some more details, as we cannot be sure what the issue is. What do you mean by `all of my clients save` - do you see it in the logs? In short, what do expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: Yeah. I see they are saving all through out.

Comment: Could you provide a log?

Comment: @BartSabayton How you are getting client.id in your form, I can't see any parameter for `client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this.

I've modified my JS:

```
  $(document).on "click", ".btn-submit-add-to-contact", ->
    $(this).prop "disabled", true
    $(this).val "Added to Contacts!"
    contact_form = $(this).closest('.add-to-contact-form').find('.ajax-form')
    contact_form.submit()
    return
```

And I put class before my form:

```
.add-to-contact-form
    = form_for(@contact, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-horizontal ajax-form add-to-contact', style: 'margin-bottom: 0;', 'data-model-name' => 'contact'}) do |f|
      = f.text_field :type, :value => 'clients'
      = f.text_field :client_id, :value => client.id
      = f.submit "Add to Contact", class: 'btn btn-success btn-submit-add-to-contact'
```

I use `.closest` and it works fine to me.
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `remote: true` if you are adding you own Ajax functionality.
Also you should prevent the default click action or the browser will submit the form twice.

```
$(document).on "click", ".btn-submit-add-to-contact", ->(e)
    $(this).prop "disabled", true
    $(this).val "Added to Contacts!"
    $(".add-to-contact").submit()
    e.preventDefault()
```

If you are using jquery-ujs you should listen for the completed ajax call instead:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("form").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
```